# django-imagekit - do not crash when source file does not exist

Tags: django, django-imagekit

I have a Django model that has an image and an autogenerated thumbnail:

```
img = ImageField(upload_to=..., max_length=64)
img_thumbnail = ImageSpecField([ResizeToFit(width=64, height=64)], source='img')
```

For a number of reasons, the `img` field may contain a filename that is no longer present in the filesystem. When the file is not there, the view crashes with a `FileNotFoundError` - `No such file or directory: '....png'`

Is it possible to configure the `img_thumbnail` field / django-imagekit to fail silently? Also without writing having to catch the exception in the view.